# Bootstrap 4 dropdown width

Tags: menu, width, dropdown

I know how to change bootstrap 4 dropdown menu width whit:

```
.dropdown-menu{ min-width: ??px;}
```

But how to change the width of only 1 specific dropdown menu if I have multiple dropdown on my navbar?

I had try whit an id like

```
#loginDropdown { min-width: ??px;}
```

addign the id to the specific dropdown menu but this doesn't work.

How to solve?

Comment: could you provide your code please? There're different ways to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
#loginDropdown { min-width: ??px !important;}
```